Replacement for the "boiling frog" metaphor
The "boiling frog" metaphor is used to highlight sensitivity to abrupt, critical changes for the worse (the frog jumping out if placed in boiling water), in contrast to insensitivity to gradual changes (the frog supposedly staying put if placed in water which is gradually heated to a boiling temperature, leading to the frog's demise).
The problem is just that the surreal second part isn't real; it's a legend. (This could be noted self-humorously as in "actually this isn't true, but you get the gist", but that would weaken the metaphor.)
Is there a strong alternative metaphor, rooted in reality, which could be used instead?

Consider a canary in a coal mine. (Apparently the practice became illegal in the UK in 1986).
Now, you might argue that the concentration of poisonous gas in the air reached a critical level for a canary before it reached a critical level for a human being.  At first glance, it seems that  the lethal effect doesn't depend upon how gradual or abrupt is the change in the quality of the air breathed.
On the other hand, if the concentration of poisonous gas in the air increased quickly enough to first affect the bird and then -- within a few seconds -- also incapacitate or kill the miners, then there likely wouldn't have been enough time for the miners to observe symptoms of poisoning in the bird and evacuate from the mine.
The miners are vulnerable to some abrupt changes, but I presume that you are looking for a sensitivity to abrupt changes  that enables the miners to save themselves.
In the boiling frog metaphor, the frog tries to escape after experiencing abrupt changes, and escape is both possible and simple.  Should that aspect of the boiling frog metaphor be included in the replacement metaphor?  There are other possibilities.
The frog doesn't need to ponder the question of whether or not it is possible to escape.  The frog doesn't need to design and test a solution to the problem.  In stories about human action, escape might not be as simple as it is for the frog.
However, perhaps nicotine addiction provides a simple replacement for the boiling frog metaphor.
Presumably, most people who become addicted to nicotine begin gradually.
Now, imagine somebody who has never smoked even one puff of a cigarette, and who has for some reason resolved to do some smoking. An agreement is made: the novice smoker will receive two free packages of cigarettes, but must try to smoke them all in one day, and there will be an eyewitness to prevent cheating, with some mercy if the novice smoker is experiencing acute nausea.
The abrupt change from never smoking to attempting to smoke two packages of cigarettes in one day would be a memorable experience and likely create an aversion to cigarettes, making it easy for the first day of smoking to be the final day of smoking.
